# How to use streams to encrypt and then stream the data to GridFs? (mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stream, gridfs

I'm currently building an application that takes in a user upload and then I want to encrypt it then save it to mongodb using the grid-fs library. I'm using multer to receive the file and them I'm trying to encrypt it then save it to the mongodb using the gridfs-stream library. Can someone take a look at this and help me out? I'm not sure how to work with streams in nodejs.

```
import { createCipher } from "crypto";
import { AES_PASSWORD } from "../config";
import stream from "stream";
import GridFs from "../models/GridFs";

const cipher = createCipher("aes-256-cbc", AES_PASSWORD);
const maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10; // 10MB
const fileChunkSize = 2 * 255 * 1024; // 510kb

const uploadController = (req,res,next) => {
  // User information
  const user_id = req.user._id;

  // File meta data from the file infromation
  const {
    mimetype,
    buffer,
    size
  } = req.file;
  const content_type = mimetype;

  // File information provided by Resumable.js
  const {
    resumableChunkNumber,
    resumableChunkSize,
    resumableCurrentChunkSize,
    resumableTotalSize,
    resumableType,
    resumableIdentifier,
    resumableFilename,
    resumableRelativePath,
    resumableTotalChunks
  } = req.body;

  /*
   * Developer's note:
   * Somehow the data being posted automatically by resumable.js
   * is of type string. Thus we have to parse the string here
   * to prevent errors when doing any comparisons
   */
  const data = buffer;
  const chunk_n = parseInt(resumableChunkNumber) - 1;
  const chunk_total = parseInt(resumableTotalChunks);
  const chunk_size = parseInt(resumableChunkSize);
  const file_length = parseInt(resumableTotalSize);
  const uid = resumableIdentifier;
  const file_name = resumableFilename;

  // Verify Chunk size as configured
  if(chunk_size != fileChunkSize){
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: "chunk_size is not equal to configured chunk size as the backend"
    });
  }

  // Ensure file size is not larger than max allowable at the moment
  if( file_length && file_length > maxFileSize) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: "file length is greater than configured maxFileSize"
    });
  }

  // Basic logic in ensuring the max number of chunks is correct when
  // there is overlap
  let expectedNumberOfChunks = file_length / chunk_size;
  if(file_length % chunk_size){
    expectedNumberOfChunks += 1;
  }
  if(chunk_n > expectedNumberOfChunks){
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: "chunk_n is greater than the number of expected chunks"
    });
  }

  const writeStream = GridFs.createWriteStream({
    content_type,
    chunk_size,
    chunk_n,
    uid,
    file_name,
    file_length,
    user_id
  });

  // All is good Start encrytion
  const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
  try{
    bufferStream.write(buffer);
    bufferStream.pipe(cipher).pipe(writeStream).on("close", () => {
      buffer.end();
      return res.status(200).send("ok");
    });
  } catch(error){
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error });
  }
};

export default uploadController;
```

Nothing is happening and the request just times out. I'm lost for words at the moment.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Where is the file coming from? Is it meant to be in the upload request? if in the request then surely this should be exposed as a filehandle by whatever middleware is used, but i'm not seeing anything attempting to read from such a handle, which would presumably be on `req` here. if it's available as a "stream" and your crypto deals with streams it should just be a matter of piping from source through crypto and then finally to the writeStream of GridFS to create. But I cannot see the source.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't include which middleware I was using. I'm using multer.js which populates the req.body object with the information about the file being uploaded.

Comment: So where's the handle and the input stream? You need to open the input stream somewhere. That's what I'm not seeing. Unless I'm just missing it completely

Comment: I thought it was somewhere there. Is it possible to transform a buffer into a read stream and then pipe that into the crypto stream into the gridfs? It's on the line where I call bufferStream to be a stream pass through

Comment: What buffer? This is basically what I am saying. I don't see where there is any attempt to actually open the uploaded content as a stream. Hence this will just hang and do nothing. If a file is uploaded then it will be created in the filesystem as a temporyary file or something. But your middleware should be able to tell you where that file is. Then you open a read stream to the file location, and pipe and so on. Get it?

Comment: Oh I'm not saving the file into anywhere. That was one of the requirements by the client. It's loaded into memory only so no chance of saving it accidentally

Comment: I don't think you get it. What do you see in `req.files`? Or did you set `inMemory` for multer? Though I don't know why you would use GridFS if the latter was true. `req.files` should be where you can open the stream from.

Comment: I did set inmemory for multer. Why is that a problem?

Comment: If you don't set it then you can open a file as a stream. If you can set it then I don't know why you would be using GridFS at all. More than enough info here for you to debug this now.

Comment: Did you get this to work? Even I am looking out for encrypting the stream before passing it to gridfs, would like to know if managed it with the above snippet